# slow loading d3 / c3 chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, c3

I have a page with two d3 - c3 charts which are fed by json data. It takes nearly 4 seconds to load. Why is it soo slow? I can't figure it out. There are not that many data points to be plot. 
http://skiweather.eu/snowdata/obertilliach/852

Comment: How much stuff is there in between the code and the server get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at Developer Tools it is the initial response from the server that takes up a lot of time and not the d3 / c3 scripts. You might want to look at the backend script that generates the page.